# Efficient way to keep referencing a class in multiple linked java classes?

Tags: java

suppose in Eclipse I have three packages with the following classes in each:

Packages: Classes

Head: head.java

Body: arms.java

Legs: feet.java

I want to define class info in brain.java and pass it through methods to the other classes (arms.java and feet.java) and update the contents of info.

```
class info {
    // some vars such as bools,ints,strings
}
```

For example, have updateArms be a method defined in arms.java. I want to do the following in brain.java:

```
arms.updateArms( info );
```

I am having trouble finding how to first define a class that behaves this way, and secondly how to pass it as a parameter to another linked class.

Comment: Java tutorial: [Initializing Fields.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: Don't think about *classes*, **think** about *instances*.

Comment: If you want to share the data there are different things to take into consideration. The most efficient way would maybe using static fields but as far as you want to change the values you need to assure, that there is no Threading is going on. In that case you need to think about synchronization. But what I think you need is a simple Observer-Pattern implementation. The problem to provide you a solution for me is regarding the interaction of Head and Body for example. When is updateArms called for example.

Comment: Learn about Java naming convention first.  Regarding your design, you should think like : I want a brain to send command to a connected arm and ask the arm to do something.  That's the way OOP see things

Answer (score 0):

First, you should learn about Java naming convention.

For example, package should be `head`, and the class should be `Head`.

Go back to your design: In OOP, we see the program as interactions between object instances.

In your example, it may look like:

```
class Arm {
    void moveUp(SomeInfo info) {
        ...
    }
}

class Brain {
    private Arm leftArm;
    private Arm rightArm;

    void reachForward() {
        rightArm.moveUp(...);
    }

    void connectLeftArm(Arm arm) {
        this.leftArm = arm;
    }
    //....
}

class Body {
    Brain brain;
    Arm leftArm;
    Arm rightArm;
    public Body() {
        this.brain = new Brain();
        this.leftArm = new Arm();
        this.rightArm = new Arm();
        this.brain.connectLeftArm(this.leftArm);
        this.brain.connectRightArm(this.rightArm);
    }
}
```

I wish this demonstrate the difference of way of thinking.

If you start get used to the way OOP see things, then you can take next step in refining your design (e.g. by different design pattern)

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this using Inheritance.

Inheritance can be defined as the process where one class acquires the properties (methods and fields) of another. With the use of inheritance the information is made manageable in a hierarchical order. The class which inherits the properties of other is known as subclass (derived class, child class) and the class whose properties are inherited is known as superclass (base class, parent class).

Sample Code helps you how to use the methods and properties of other classes.

```
 class Calculation {
   int z;

   public void addition(int x, int y) {
      z = x + y;
      System.out.println("The sum of the given numbers:"+z);
   }

   public void Subtraction(int x, int y) {
      z = x - y;
      System.out.println("The difference between the given numbers:"+z);
   }
}

public class My_Calculation extends Calculation {
   public void multiplication(int x, int y) {
      z = x * y;
      System.out.println("The product of the given numbers:"+z);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int a = 20, b = 10;
      My_Calculation demo = new My_Calculation();
      demo.addition(a, b);
      demo.Subtraction(a, b);
      demo.multiplication(a, b);
   }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell but I don't think the OP is asking about inheritance. Also, there isn't an inheritance relationship between head, arms and legs.